# Why do these nested Observables only get called once?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a nested series of observables like this:

```js
this.subscription = combineLatest(
  [1$, ..., m$]
).pipe(
  filter((latest: [boolean, ..., number]) => {
    const [1, ..., m] = latest;
    const shouldContinue: boolean = <some logic>;
    return shouldContinue;
  }),
  concatMap((latest: [boolean, ..., number]) => {
    const [1, ..., m] = latest;

    // Hits here first time, then never again

    return <method that returns an Observable>().pipe(concatMap((result: [boolean, ..., number]) => {
      const [2, ..., n] = result;

      // Hits here first time, then never again

      return <another method that returns an Observable>();
    }));
  })
).subscribe((result: [boolean, ..., number]) => {
  const [3, ..., o] = result;

  // Hits here first time, then never again

  <some method>();
});
```

The first time `shouldContinue` is set to `true`, the remaining functions are called all the way into the subscription.

But the second time `shouldContinue` is set to `true` (I can see it set in the debugger), the code never moves into the `concatMap`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Any way to do a stackblitz that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: concatMap only yields a second time once all the observables in it yield. [This page](https://angular-academy.com/rxjs-switchmap-concatmap-mergemap-exhaustmap/#concatmap) has a good explanation on how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to make the inner observables hot - adding [`share()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share) solved the problem.